# How to have the logo in the middle then move out to the right position?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a landing page where:

1. First of all you see the logo of the website in the middle of the screen.
2. Then I want it to move to its proper position. And then the full page loads.

Is this possible?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT2:
Now I have this:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").delay("1000").animate({top:"-=30px", width:"300px", height:"300px",})
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="loader"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_(2011).png') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

But now the image, doesnt resize but just crops the sides of this images.
So you get this as a page: http://prntscr.com/47t9rg

Some help?

Comment: Yes, this is possibile using javascript/jquery or CSS3

Comment: Try it... if you found any issue or stuck some where post the code and explain the issue we will help you... good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just search/try some thing instead of asking entire code.

Try below code, this may work.

```
$(".loader").animate({
  left: someValue,
  top: someValue
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Is it then also possible to resize the image, while its moving to the proper position?

Comment: sure you can add height and width comma separated. But before asking at least try yourself

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you should use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
   jQuery(".loader").delay("1000").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Second, you'll want to use [jQuery's animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Then, simply change the left position to wherever you want it to go.

Comment: Again: Is it then also possible to resize the image, while its moving to the proper position?

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is set it as width: somevalue, height:somevalue directly below what he has: $(".loader").animate({
  left: someValue,
  top: someValue, width:somevalue,height:somevalue
}, 1000)

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and wrap the animation within `$(document).ready(`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Logo").animate({
        left: "-=100px"
    }, 1000, function () {
        // Animation complete.
        //Send AJAX Request to fetch content, or redirect to another page?
    });
});
```

## [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9Lmp/)

#### What this does;

- Wait until the document is ready (all elements have loaded)
- Animate the `#Logo` element to go left 100px (in the CSS on JSFiddle, that is half the width of the container) - resulting in it being in the top left corner